# Restricting IPs that can connect to postfix by domain

Tags: postfix

We are using a 3rd party smtp relay service that forwards all our incoming email to our postfix server.

I've been firewalling (via iptables) the smtp port to only allow connections from this relay, but recently they changed their infrastructure and we blocked email for a couple of days.

Is it possible in postfix to restrict the smtpd to only connections when the reverse lookup of the connection's IP falls in this 3rd party's domain?  It isn't as secure as I'd like as iptables, but seems a bit more robust than trying to reverse engineer their hosts.

There are some similar questions, but they appear to be about restricting the sender (via envelope) -- not the host.

Answer (score 0):

[SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) might be of some assistance to do that, see [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF), for example.

tl;dr: you need something to check SPF for you (the guide gives two examples), and the choices seem to involve picking between python- and perl-based solutions.

It seems (to me) a little 'stronger' (and possibly easier to setup/rely on) than reverse lookups alone (although I guess it sort of amounts to the same), and should allow some flexibility in case the provider has any issues with their DNS setup

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions should let you do this, possibly with `check_reverse_client_hostname_a_access`